# Sencha Touch: clone record

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to clone a Sencha Touch 2.3 Model instance (also called "record"). The clone should have the same id as the old one, but it should not be attached to any store. In ExtJS4, I would do the following and it would work:

```
var newRecord = record.copy();
```

This does not work in Sencha Touch. As per ST2 documentation, the new record gets a newly generated id on [`copy()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-copy). So I tried:

```
var newRecord = record.copy(record.getId());
```

So now I should have a new copy with the same id.

```
newRecord.getId()==record.getId(); // returns true
```

I then modify the record:

```
newRecord.set("myCount",newRecord.get("myCount")+1);
```

Guess what happens next? I check that the records are really different:

```
newRecord.get("myCount")!=record.get("myCount"); // returns false
```

So, when I modified the "copy", I also modified the original, which means that no copy was created.

What am I doing wrong, where did I misread the Sencha Touch docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

record.copy(id) will return a reference to the existing record if you pass the same id as record.

var newRecord = record.copy() will create another instance of the record so it will have a different id but its not attached to the current store. You can verify that as shown :

```
record.stores  //Returns store reference in array
newRecord.stores //Returns [] indicating no store refeerences
```

You can copy the record and set the id of newRecord to id of original record if you want like this.

```
var newRecord = record.copy()
newRecord .set('id',record.getId()) //newRecord.getId() returns same as record.getId()
```

Comment: `record.copy(record.getId());` does not work as long as `useCache:true` is set on the model. It works as soon as I set `useCache:false`.